# split-lapply- combine a large dataframe to avoid memory issues?

Tags: r, memory, runtime, apply, lapply

I have a situation where the usage of split-apply-combine might run into runtime memory issues. The task is to identify the common elements across all the simulations.

```
numListFull <- replicate(1000, sample(1:55000, sample(54900:55000), 
                                  replace = FALSE))
format(object.size(numListFull), units = "auto", standard = "SI")
# [1] "66 MB"

# Create list of nums shared by all simulations
numListAll <- numListFull[[1]]
numList <- lapply(numListFull[2:length(numListFull)],
                    function(x){intersect(x, numListAll)})
format(object.size(numList), units = "auto", standard = "SI")
# [1] "65.7 MB"

numListAll <- Reduce(intersect, numList)
format(object.size(numListAll), units = "auto", standard = "SI")
# [1] "166.4 kB"
```

When the replications are increased from `300` to `1000`, the sizes are `219.9 MB`, `219.9 MB` and `87.5 kB`.

Sometimes the replications would cross even 10000 i.e., 10 times the latter situation. Would you know of any better way of doing this to avoid the memory issues in the computer?

Is something like this **sensible**?

```
numList <- lapply(split(2:length(numListFull), rep_len(1:100,length(numListFull))), 
                  function(ind){
                    lapply(numListFull[ind], 
                           function(x){
                             intersect(x, numListAll)})})
format(object.size(numList), units = "auto", standard = "SI")  
# [1] "87.5 MB"
```

*Update:* Ofcourse for loop works like charm without memory issues, but at the cost of parallelization!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing apples to apples ;-)

If I get it right, the end-result should be a list or vector containing only those items present in **all** samples, right?
Because right now, you're comparing all you samples with the first one, which is way too much work. Let's take a look at a smaller example, and what you are actually storing.
We'll do the same is in your code, except
`numListFull <- replicate(10, sample(1:1, sample(8:10, size=1)))`
(side-note: giving `size=1` will speed up your code somewhat as well, though not by much)
Anyway, after running your code, `numList` now contains all values not present in **the first sample**, but it still has a lot of values duplicated, and values which could have been removed.
That's no different in your second try, there you're still comparing all sample with the first one, although I'm not entirely sure what you tried to do there.

Honestly, I think a for-loop may not be the worst here. As soon as you know some values are either not in the first, or not in the second sample, there's no use in comparing these values with those present in the third. So if

```
firststep <- intersect(numListFull[[1]], numListFull[[2]])
```

then the best next step is comparing `numListFull[[3]]` to that `firststep`, instead of looking at `numListFull[[1]]` again. Which means your result gets constantly updated, and a for-loop would be best.
Just keep track of all values present in all samples up to that point, instead of storing all kind of intermediate results.

## Or parallel

It is possible to do it parallelized, but then you have to calculate things individually. So compare sample1 with sample2, and meanwhile compare 3 with 4; 5 with 6, etc.
I think that's more in the spirit of the way big data is handled: calculate on a small chunk, so to reduce to a result that can be passed on. But visualise it as a binary tree: at each step, a result that's at most half as big gets passed on.
I think that's what you were trying to do in your second example. At least I get this:

```
numListFull <- lapply(split(numListFull, 
   rep(1:ceiling(length(numListFull)/2), each=2)[seq_len(length(numListFull))]), function(dfs) {
     if(length(dfs)==2) {
       return(intersect(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]]))
     } else {
       # Can be just one
       return(dfs[[1]])
     }
   })
```

Of course this is just one step, but if you put it in a while-loop it continues until it's just length 1.
For memory, numListFull gets overwritten at each loop, so garbage-control can always reduce memory-usage to something smaller than what we started with.

On the other hand, debugging it may be harder than in a for-loop, and I'm not sure how much parallelisation already occurs in `intersect`. Anyway, you have to replace `lapply` with `parallel::mclapply` to get those benefits, and if you're running things on a normal desktop or laptop, you also get to another memory-problem, i.e. that caching gets more difficult.
In a for-loop the processor can keep the relevant data in cache, maybe even look ahead to get data it will need in a little while. However, if you insist on doing things parallel, that means working on different parts of what's is memory, meaning all data has to be written away and retrieved again. Which may well balance any gains you get by using multiple cores.